Load a csv with comma as separator in hive where one column of unquoted string can have a comma in it
Goal: load a given .csv into hive.
Problem: one unquoted string column from that .csv has commas in it in certain rows. This produces rows where there are more commas than columns, making data wrong in those rows.
Example inside the .csv:
Id,Name,City,Ranking,Rating,PriceRange,NumberOfReviews
1,Cafe Q,Lisbon,104,4.5,exp,999
2,Quarto Burguer,Rome,1920,4.0,exp,569
3,Gertrude's Cafe, L'angolo dell'amore,Budapest,55,4.5,med,397
4,Rincon Bar,Valencia,23,4.5,cheap,904

As seen, the third row's name is "Gertrude's Cafe, L'angolo dell'amore", which adds a comma to the row.
How can I load this file in Hive and transform "Gertrude's Cafe, L'angolo dell'amore" into something without the comma?
This is my table creator and data loading code.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS restaurant 
(
    Id INT,
    Name STRING,
    City STRING,
    Ranking DOUBLE,
    Rating DOUBLE,
    PriceRange STRING,
    NumberOfReviews INT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/hive/path_etc'
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");

and then
LOAD DATA INPATH '/path/to/my_file.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE restaurant;

The only thing I tried was a chatgpt answer which added a third step:
-- Step 3: Update the column to replace commas with single quotes
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE restaurant
SELECT 
    Id,
    regexp_replace(Name, ',', '\'') as Name,
    City,
    Ranking,
    Rating,
    PriceRange,
    NumberOfReviews
FROM 
    restaurant;

but it didn't work, it simply erased the first row, and left the "bad" row unaffected. I also tried adding regex, but my bad tries didn't result in anything working

Pre-process the data into being a valid CSV file, which this is not?  The language of your choice could read each line right-to-left to find the real comma for the name field and change it to ", (adding quote) then read left-to-right to find the id column comma and change it to ," (adding the other quote)

Oh, I was wondering if any preprocessing could be evaded. By saying this file is not a valid csv file, does it mean the preprocessing cannot be evaded at all? I guess mixing the delimiter in unquoted strings breaks any possibility of doing it in a more direct manner?

This problem is about semantics. Can you ask for the data to be re-exported? If just one column has the "over use" of ',' then it is possible to solve your problem. But if there is more than one column then it will depend on preprocessing and the amount of data you got.

I see. In this particular case I can modify the data myself, so preprocessing can still be used thankfully.
If only this column had this problem, would it still be "fixable" without preprocessing?

The problem is CSV is comma-separated fields.  If you add random commas then the fields don't match the data.  You need to quote the fields that may contain commas, or use some escaping scheme that the importer knows about.  I'm making this one up, but for example adding \ before commas inside field text.  You can fix things by changing the field data to remove commas, changing the export to quote or escape commas, or adding a preprocessor app or script in between export and import that can find the right places to add quotes.  (Might be impossible with multiple text fields with commas)

I would have expected:
regexp_replace(Name, ',', '\'') as Name,

to be:
regexp_replace(Name, ',', '\,') as Name,

Have you tried this?

Just tried it, with other character to replace the coma with, but it doesn't work this way
